# Group data into small chunk (big data issue)

Tags: r, grouping, bigdata

I was looking for an answer to group data into small chunks in R. Let's say I have

```
df = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 5), b = c(2, 3, 2, 4, 4))
```

I want to have a new column to specify the group id. Rows having same value of either a or b will be grouped into one group. The group id will incremented for each new group.

The final output for the sample would be

```
Group a b 
1    1  2 
2    2  3 
1    3  2 
1    1  4 
1    5  4
```

The problem is actually not new. I could solve it with for loops

```
i.range = nrow(a) - 1
j.range = nrow(a)
k = 2
df$group_id = 1

for(i in 1:i.range){
  for(j in 2:j.range){
    #if not a new group
    if (df[j,"a"] == df[i, "a"] | 
          df[j, "b"] == df[i, "b"]) df[j, "group_id"] = df[i, "group_id"]
    else{
      df[j, "group_id"] = k
      k = k+1
    }  
  }
}
```

The problem is my data frame has more than 40k rows. Two loops could cost it forever to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do (if I understand correctly) is to find clusters in a graph. You can see your `a` and `b` columns as nodes in the graph and each row indicates a link between nodes. Nodes in the `a` column are different from the ones in the `b` column (again, correct me if I'm wrong).

Here is our strategy:

- load the `igraph` library, that let us build and analyze graphs;
- give a numeric index to each different value of the `a` and `b` column, through `factor` and considering that the `b` column indices have to be different from the `a` ones;
- build a graph from the `matrix` obtained in the previous point;
- call the `igraph::clusters` function that returns for each node the cluster whom it belongs;
- finally indicates for each row of the original `data.frame` the relative cluster.

Here we are:

```
require(igraph)
#make a copy of the original df, just in case you want to preserve it
df2<-df
#getting indices for each "node"
df[]<-lapply(df,function(x) as.numeric(factor(x)))
#getting different indices for the b column
df$b<-df$b + max(df$a)
#building the graph
mygraph<-graph.edgelist(as.matrix(df))
#obtaining the clusters
clus<-clusters(mygraph)
#and finally..
df2$group<-clus$membership[df$a]
#  a b group
#1 1 2     1
#2 2 3     2
#3 3 2     1
#4 1 4     1
#5 5 4     1
```

Comment: Hi Nicola, it is not working for my problem. Perhaps, in my real data, the value of a and b are characters. I found a lot of NA values at the end in my group column.

Comment: I add my file here just in case somebody would like to observe
[link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30872591/test.csv)

Comment: I just tried `df<-read.csv("test.csv")` and followed my lines. No error received and no `NA`s in the data. Everything seems to work.

Comment: Nicola. It seems working with the data having only 2 columns. I removed other columns first and used your method and no more NA could be found. I will randomly check the list and will get back to you soon. Thanks very much

Comment: Dead-on, Nicola. I mark your answer as correct. Thank you very much